# Select colums from dataframe for linear regression r

Tags: r, dplyr, linear-regression

I have a dataframe Data_Group_7_8 and would like to make a linear regression based on a factor analysis. 
The factor analysis paired variables from col 1:4 as MR1 and col 16:20 as MR2. I want to set col 1:4 as independent variable and 16:20 as dependent and tried the following code:

```
mdl <- lm(select(1:4)  ~ select(16:20), data=Data_Group_7_8) 
summary(mdl)
```

Which unfortunately doesn't work. But the following does:

```
df2 <- data.frame(x=Data_Group_7_8 %>% select(1:4),y=Data_Group_7_8 %>% select(16:20))

lrm <- lm(x.Themenwelt_1+ x.Themenwelt_2+ x.Themenwelt_3+ x.Product_demonstration ~ y.Inspired_by_1+ y.Inspired_by_2+ y.Inspired_by_3+ y.Inspired_by_4+ y.Inspired_by_5, data=df2)

summary(lrm)
```

Is there a way to select the variables (Themenwelt_1 etc.) directly from the original Data_Group_7_8 (as I have tried in code 1) instead of adding them all up from a new df as I have to do 60 different analyses with this df.

Comment: How about `lm(Data_Group_7_8[,1:4] ~ Data_Group_7_8[,16:20])`?

Comment: The following error message appears: Error in model.frame.default(formula = Data_Group_7_8[, 1:4] ~ Data_Group_7_8[,  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'Data_Group_7_8[, 16:20]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R allows you to build a formula from a string using `as.formula(str)`. Each side will have to have the sum of the terms considered, and the LHS and RHS need to be joined with a tilde. You can get the names of the columns using `names()`, then it it just a matter of pasting them together, first each side of the equation, collapsing the character vector to a single string with `collapse = '+'`, then combining the two sides separated by a tilde. This is an example with the built-in mtcars dataset:

```
regFormula <- function(dat,range1,range2){
  dat %>%
    select(range1) %>%
    names() %>%
    paste(collapse = ' + ') %>% 
    paste(dat %>% 
            select(range2) %>%
            names() %>%
            paste(collapse = ' + '),
          sep = ' ~ ') %>% 
    as.formula() 
}

regFormula(mtcars,1:3,4:5)
# mpg + cyl + disp ~ hp + drat
# <environment: 0x000000000cf55c90>
```

You can use this directly as the formula in your linear model.